# Iterator returned by set_union()

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have the following C++ code using set_union() from algorithm stl:

```
 9     int first[] = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25};
10     int second[] = {50, 40, 30, 20, 10};
11     vector<int> v(10);
12     vector<int>::iterator it;
13
14     sort(first, first+5);
15     sort(second, second+5);
16
17     it = set_union(first, first + 5, second, second + 5, v.begin());
18
19     cout << int(it - v.begin()) << endl;
```

I read through the document of set_union from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/ .  I have two questions:

- Line 17.  I understand set_union() is returning an OutputIterator.  I
  thought iterators are like an object returned from a container object
  (e.g. instantiated vector class, and calling blah.begin()
  returns the iterator object).  I am trying to understand what does
  the "it" returned from set_union point to, which object?
- Line 19.  What does "it - v.begin()" equate to.  I am guessing from the output value of "8", the size of union, but how?

Would really appreciate if someone can shed some light.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: The reference has an explanation of the return value: *An iterator to the end of the constructed range.*

Comment: I suggest always using this website instead: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union I find it is generally much more informative and complete.

Comment: I am a bit new to C++, so pardon my question, but what is a "constructed range".  Is it a new object of which class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) states that the returned iterator points past the end of constructed range, in your case to one past the last element in `v` that was written to by `set_union`.

This is the reason `it - v.begin()` results in the length of the set union also. Note that you are able to simply subtract the two only because a `vector<T>::iterator` must satisfy the RandomAccessIterator concept. Ideally, you should use `std::distance` to figure out the interval between two iterators.

Your code snippet can be written more idiomatically as follows:

```
int first[] = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25};
int second[] = {50, 40, 30, 20, 10};

std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(10);  // reserve instead of setting an initial size

sort(std::begin(first), std::end(first));       
sort(std::begin(second), std::begin(second));
// use std::begin/end instead of hard coding length

auto it = set_union(std::begin(first), std::end(first), 
                    std::begin(second), std::end(second), 
                    std::back_inserter(v));
// using back_inserter ensures the code works even if the vector is not 
// initially set to the right size

std::cout << std::distance(v.begin(), it) << std::endl;
std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
// these lines will output the same result unlike your example
```

---

In response to your comment below

> What is the use of creating a vector of size 10 or reserving size 10

In your original example, creating a `vector` having initial size of at least 8 is necessary to prevent undefined behavior because `set_union` is going to write 8 elements to the output range. The purpose of reserving 10 elements is an optimization to prevent possibility of multiple reallocations of the `vector`. This is typically not needed, or feasible since you won't know the size of the result in advance.

> I tried with size 1, works fine

Size of 1 definitely does NOT work fine with your code, it is undefined behavior. `set_union` will write past the end of the `vector`. You get a seg fault with size 0 for the same reason. There's no point in speculating why the same thing doesn't happen in the first case, that's just the nature of undefined behavior.

> Does set_union trim the size of the vector, from 10 to 8. Why or is that how set_union() works

You're only passing an iterator to `set_union`, it knows *nothing* about the underlying container. So there's no way it could possibly trim excess elements, or make room for more if needed. It simply keeps writing to the output iterator and increments the iterator after each write. This is why I suggested using [`back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator), that is an iterator adaptor that will call `vector::push_back()` whenever the iterator is written to. This guarantees that `set_union` will never write beyond the bounds of the `vector`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Two questions.  1) What is the use of creating a vector of size 10 or reserving size 10.  I tried with size 1, works fine. But when I set size to nothing, just "std::vector<int> v()".  I get a seg fault, why?  2) Does set_union trim the size of the vector, from 10 to 8.  Why or is that how set_union() works.

Comment: Thank you again.  A uick questions , I am assuming begin(first) is equivalent to first.begin().

Comment: @AhmedA `first.begin()` will not compile because `first` is a plain old C-style array, it doesn't have any member functions. The beauty of [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) is that it works for plain arrays, or evaluates to `arg.begin()` assuming the member function exists. Same applies to `std::end`.

Answer (score 0):

first: "it" is an iterator to the end of the constructed range (i.e. equivalent to v.end())

second: it - v.begin() equals 8 because vector iterators are usually just typedefed pointers and therefore it is just doing pointer arithmetic. In general, it is better to use the distance algorithm than relying on raw subtraction

```
cout << distance(v.begin(), it) << endl;
```

Comment: It's a little misleading to say the subtraction works because `vector` iterators are usually just raw pointers. The reason it works is because RandomAccessIterators are required to allow subtraction, and vector iterators must be RandomAccessIterators.